# How can you have luggage moved cheaply within England, if you do not care about delivery speed?

Tags: uk, luggage, england, shipping

1. My grandmother will be travelling within England (London, Cambridge, Portsmouth)  for the next year.
2. Her health problems prohibit moving her 3 suitcases herself WITHIN England; each weighs 25 kg and around 55 cm x 35 cm x 25 cm.
3. My grandmother can live off  her wheeled carry-on (that she can move) for 14 days: thus delivery speed does not matter.
4. The 3 suitcases must be collected between 9 AM - 12 noon.

Are there cheaper solutions than expensive couriers (DHL, FedEx, Purolator, UPS), or even Royal Mail or Parcelforce (they seem to offer only delivery within 48 hours that she does NOT need)?

Comment: Why does your grandmother have to handle her luggage herself? EG What assistance will the airport supply?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into shipping companies targeted at students. They usually have a decent offering at the "a few bags or boxes" level for people moving long distance for a few months or a year, and wanting to do so cheaply as the most important factor - exactly the sort of thing you're looking at here.

Comment: Royal Mail Signed For 2nd Class is £29.65 for £20kg. http://www.royalmail.com/personal/uk-delivery/signed-2nd-class

Comment: @PeterM My questions concerns WITHIN England. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @PeterM I read the question as "moving around within the UK", not the coming-from-Canada part - going between those three cities will almost certainly be by train or coach, not flying. Train companies will usually provide assistance with getting bags on/off if you ask in advance, but relying on it working with three large suitcases might be risky - the London-Cambridge trains, for example, are very much commuter services and aren't really set up to handle that much baggage.

Comment: I use man with a van type services; I've been with the same guy for like 15 years for whatever.

Comment: @GayotFow Can you please recommend him to me then?

Comment: If the question is truly just about moving around England then you should edit out all references to Canada as that part is irrelevant

Comment: @Andrew Your reading is correct. PeterM misunderstood my question, but I am to blame because I did not specify.

Comment: @PeterM I removed Canada. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Well, the question still implies she's coming from Canada.  Can you describe how she will be moving from place to place withing the UK?

Comment: @Johns-305 She herself will probably take the bus or train. But she needs the 3 suitcases moved separately.

Comment: We can't make recommendations like that because it's spamish. But you go to Google and type in your postcode with 'man and van', like SW1 3QX man and van' and you will see them by the dozens.

Comment: @GayotFow Can you do so in a chat with me? It is too risky to pay ANY man and a van. A recommendation is safer.

Comment: Anyvan.com and Shiply.com are worth a look - both allow transport providers to bid on your shipment. Usually it's van/lorry drivers who are doing that route already and have spare space in the truck. I've used both successfully.

Comment: my guy doesn't operate out of Cambs, he's an Essex guy. Honestly, they are fine.

Comment: I suppose it's ok to say he trades out of 'a 2 b removals' though :)

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of websites (one is called uShip) that allow you to post details of a big or small removal job, and have removal companies, men with vans etc. bid for them. Because you get a large number of bids, and they are in competition with each other, you can get a very good price. Another advantage is that many will be taking a particular route anyway and are just looking to fill up spare space, so you don't need to pay for an entire van.

http://www.uship.com

https://www.shiply.com

https://www.anyvan.com/

Comment: That looks like a nice answer, but could you include links, ideally to more than one such website? +1 and welcome to Travel SE!

Answer (score 4):

The best option is to use a comparison site such as https://uremovals.com. As mentioned above. If you use a comparison site, you don't need to call every removal company or man and van for a quote. Much easier and a time saver. Just give them your details, and you can see the prices and company reputations in the same place.

I have relations with this site which is mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning you have relations with the site!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a man and van comparison site or local man and van company, that way you can get a direct price with support on your query/booking from professional customer service

Such as

[https://www.themanvan.co.uk/](https://findmymanandvan.co.uk/man-with-a-van/london)

https://findmymanandvan.co.uk/man-with-a-van/london

I am connected to the latter site but not the former