# How can 4 suitcases be collected between 9 AM - 12 noon in England to be moved, without using 'man with a van'?

Tags: luggage, england

1. My cousin accidentally left 4 suitcases in Nottingham, England (London, Cambridge, Portsmouth) that she needs moved to London. My cousin does not live in England, will not be travelling to Nottingham again, and will travel only to London.
2. Each suitcase each weighs 23 kg and around 55 cm x 35 cm x 25 cm.
3. The suitcases must be collected between 9 AM - 12 noon.

The problem is that she does not trust random people with a van as suggested [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77939/47623), because of the number of complaints. So are there any other suggestions or solutions, besides collecting these suitcases in person?

Companies like ParcelForce or UPS cannot help here, because ParcelForce does not guarantee pickup time windows and UPS requires all suitcases to be boxed, but she is obviously not in England to box the suitcases.

Comment: Who has possession and control of the suitcases now?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I think a hostel does: their staff have agreed to hand over the suitcases to the delivery person.

Comment: What do you mean by “London, Cambridge, Portsmouth” in the first line?  The suitcases are all in Nottingham, right?  Or are you saying that some of the suitcases might in those other places?

Comment: Could she take a day trip from London to Nottingham (under 2 hours each way by train), box the suitcases to UPS requirements, and then have UPS move them? She might reduce the problem by bringing two suitcases back with her.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because "Nottingham, England (London, Cambridge, Portsmouth)" is unclear. Will retract my voted if edited.

Comment: I'm confused. On say, Anyvan, every individual is reviewed. Some of them may have bad review, but I've always had bids from people with 100s of excellent reviews. Why not just pick one of the well reviewed people?

Comment: Just curious: how do you leave 4 suitcases weighting a total of 92kg somewhere "accidentally" ?

Comment: Are you sure UPS requires the items to be boxed? Have you confirmed this with them? I'm sure they would prefer it, but I'm not that certain that they would only accept boxes. There's actually a [whole page dedicated to "Irregular Shaped Items"](https://www.ups.com/content/gb/en/resources/ship/packaging/guidelines/pack_irregular.html) on their site.

Comment: @jcaron Upvoted! Thanks. You are perfectly correct - they do NOT require items to be boxed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a bit out of the box, but you might find a user on [TaskRabbit](https://www.taskrabbit.co.uk/) willing to pick them up and take them on a train down to London for her, especially if she's willing to meet them at the train station in London.  For the right fee, it's amazing what you'll find people doing on there, and it's not exactly complicated, especially if she covers their train fare.

Note that TaskRabbit vetts and background checks all users, and runs as a company providing a million dollars insurance guarantee on every task. It's much, much more than a 'man in a van' that seems to be her current concern.